# Bubble sorting associative arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, bubble-sort

I need to sort items in an array without using a shorthand sort in bash
Starting with an array like this

```
declare -A friends=(["Bob"]=22 ["Alice"]=19 ["Jane"]=21)
```

I have to print the items in the array in alphabetical order using the keys(Names) as sort parameters.
Expected output

```
Alice 19
Bob 22
Jane 21
```

Comment: You *can* write a bubble sort function, but this is the point where you stop trying to write your script in `bash` and use a general-purpose language.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some effort, Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
declare -A friends=(["Bob"]=22 ["Alice"]=19 ["Jane"]=21)

friendslen=${#friends[@]}
function sortByName(){
    for ((a=0; a<friendslen; a++)) ; do
        lowest=$a
 for ((b=a; b < friendslen; b++)) ; do
     if [ ${friends[b]} -le ${friends[$lowest]}] ; then
  lowest=$b
     fi
 done
 temp=${friends[a]}
 friends[a]=${friends[lowest]}
 friends[lowest]=$temp
    done
    for ((a=0; a < friendslen; a++)); do
 echo -e "${friends[$a]}"
    done
    echo ""
}
sortByName`

Answer (score -1):

bubble sort  in bash looks like this :

```
arr=(10 8 20 100 12) #Numbers Array

echo "Array in original order"
echo ${arr[*]}

# Performing Bubble sort 
for ((i = 0; i<5; i++))
do

    for((j = i; j<5-i-1; j++))
    do

        if ((${arr[j]} > ${arr[$((j+1))]}))
        then
            # swap
            temp = ${arr[$j]}
            arr[$j] = ${arr[$((j+1))]}  
            arr[$((j+1))] = $temp
        fi
    done
done

echo "Array in sorted order :"
echo ${arr[*]}
```

Comment: This is not valid bash and fails on the first line with ``line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('``

Comment: Good in sorting numbers, i needed to sort the array using Names.

Comment: @thatotherguy the spaces betweenarray assignment, are the cause of error.

Comment: @otherguy Spaces are causing the error.Sorry for bad formatting.

Comment: @AayushPathak This is still not valid. Please run it and make sure it works first.